# How to generate octet string in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, spring-ldap

I want to set password in active directory using using java/spring ldap api. AD schema for attribut userPassword says Octet string. How can I generate any password to octet string ?

If I have password "tempPassword" - how can I convert to octet string ?

Comment: SNMP4J offers [OctetString](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/smi/OctetString.html), does that help you?

Comment: @Glains this is just wrapper for byte array: `byte[] getValue()`

Comment: That's what [octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#cite_note-Bemer_2000-18)   [string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Non-text_strings) means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Octet string are just bytes:

```
byte[] octetString = "tempPassword".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, octetString).toString(16));
```

Comment: I thin you generate hexstring not octedstring

Comment: @Jens I have printed hexstring, but there is octed string in variable "octetString" :D